# PDF rendered as text

Tags: php, apache, pdf

I'm using PHP to generate a PDF via browser for my web-application. Recently, the client changed the webserver to Apache and now this feature is no longer working. Instead of generating the PDF, the browser is showing the PDF as text, just as it was ignoring Content-Type (that is set to "application/pdf"). In fact, I successfully simulated the problem by commenting the line setting the Content-Type in the source code.

I need ideas about where and what to look for, any help will be very welcome :)

Comment: How do you set the Content-Type header, could you show your code?
Is the header set before any output?

Comment: I do: header("Content-type: application/pdf");. And yes, the header is set before any output.

Comment: Then, could you dump the headers that your browser actually receives?
Also try to explicitly set `header("Content-Disposition: inline");`

Answer (score 2):

Since you generate PDF files through PHP, you can try to add these headers:

```
$file_default = 'default filename you want to appear when the user downloads.pdf';
$file_location = '/path/to/file.pdf';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_default);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_location));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file_location);
```

Comment: I tried that. It's working on development, but not on prodution (different versions of apache). I tried "header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_default);" to force the download of the pdf but no good. Any ideas why? Any configuration missing perhaps?

Comment: what are you getting, the file in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd have to force apache to download PDF content rather than showing:

check this: http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/06-08-2007/force-a-pdf-to-download

Comment: I tried "header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_default);" to force that behaviour. Saddly, it's not working on prodution (it's just as it was inline), but it is on development. Any ideas why? Any configuration missing perhaps?